# Red pixels only when im watching a certain videos on Youtube and goes away when i go fullscreen and when i watch the video for abit?

Tags: google-chrome, video, display, graphics-card, youtube

It's not a dead pixel and also my old monitor didnt do this. I had this monitor brand new 2 days ago it usually wont do these red pixels back then. Its also not the gpu im certain. I didnt experience any symptom of artifacting ever. So what would be causing this? Oh and when i up and down the red pixels would be temporarily gone but the moment i hover my cursor on the video it would come back. The fix is also that i need to watch a 4K video and the red pixels are gone for now until i restart chrome again.

When im gaming i dont usually encounter these issues. No pixels etc. only when it comes to "Some" Youtube videos. some arent affected and some are. The red pixels usually are at a black surface. When i pause the video the red pixels are there but when i hover my cursor to them. The pixels wont stay on the monitor it's like the video is the problem? This only ever happens to some videos on YouTube usually on dark spots or like small tiny spots you can catch onto. It only ever applies to some youtube videos, mostly not. mostly yes. If i try to take a screenshot using windows the pixels go away.

Monitor - AOC 24G2SE VA

Recieved this monitor with no damage on the box.

Did a dead pixel test and nothing came out of it no dead pixels.

Even resetted the settings and to no avail. Still have a 3 year warranty so yeah.

Still havent tried a clean driver uninstall so yeah could be that and this is the first time im using DisplayPort. as to back then HDMI. It also seems like if i try to zoom in on the video using Chrome's Zoom it would zoom it and make it go away for abit until i play the video and some spots still have red pixels if i set the zoom back to 100% but the pixels would go away the moment i watch lets say a 4k video literally 0. I really hope too that its not the gpu though i still have a 2 month warranty from it.

UPDATE: The red pixels gradually lessened somehow after sometime.

It's not the GPU. I took a screenshot of where the artifacts are and the artifacts did not remain on the screenshot so this could probably be a damaged cable or a damaged screen?

Here's what i did: So here are my analysis:Uninstalled/Reinstalled the Drivers - didnt workReverted the Driver to a old version - didnt workTried Different Browsers and watched the same video - the red pixels are there but only if with Hardware AccelerationTried different monitors - not tried it yet.Tried different DisplayPort slots on gpu - didnt work either.

The odd part is that i tried watching the video with Hardware Acceleration and with Microsoft Basic Display Adapter right. And the red pixels werent present. So either this could be my GPU or my Monitor or my Monitor DP Cable.

Only Fixes are: Watching a 4K Video and that would make it cease and restarting chrome would make it pop up again.
Turning off Hardware Acceleration - Permanently Fixes It unless you turn it back on.
Watching it fullscreen - also fixes it but if you dont go to full screen mode the issues will start coming back.

I have no clue whats causing this im also gonna send in a video for demonstration (*using this yt video in particular*) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QefxSdW-AN0&t=589s&ab_channel=hojiggle
https://youtu.be/pg1jDERRfIA it'd appear on dark contrasted areas but if i look at dark contrasted areas on games it wouldnt happen.

Comment: For all i know this started happening when i got this new monitor. And this is really really really BRAND new. just got this 3 days ago. I also did a dead pixel test alot and nothing came out of it even when gaming it wont surface. Either this would be a odd bug on my Monitor. Or this is something else but im thinking its the monitor cause the gpu is working quite well and there are no issues/problems. No artifacts they are only present when watching certain youtube videos. But on all 4k videos nah.

Comment: Soynds like a driver or codec bug.

Comment: tried another browser not based with Chromium and it was working flawlessly i used Firefox in my case but could this really be a Google Chrome, Opera GX problem/ Chromium Problem?

Comment: Switched to another monitor and the monitor in question is in pristine condition no bugs, no errors, no defects, etc. Issue still persists. Even switching old nvidia drivers and google chrome versions. Probably a faulty windows?